# How to enable Azure Blog Trigger listen to multiple container?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-function-app, azure-blob-trigger

I want to create a blob trigger that can listen to multiple container.
currently i can see with blob trigger we don't have listener to multiple container.

My requirement is i need to add the listener to all container with prefix ==> *-input

```
* can be any string
Example:
1. 1234-input
2. 234-input
```

As example above i want to add listener to both of the container whenever there is input to blob storage.

i see some people suggesting to use Event Grid but i am not able to get how to implement it using either python/java

Comment: Have you test it, is it work?

Comment: yes i tested it worked fine

Comment: If it works can you mark my answer as the answer to end this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1, Simply to say, if you want to use blobtrigger to achieve this, **it is not possible!**

2, The way to achieve your requirement is to use event grid trigger. And set a event grid trigger as the endpoint.

For example, if you want to listen containers end with -input, just use below settings of event grid subsciption is ok.

[image]

With above settings, all container with -input suffix will be listened.

**Repeat, blobtrigger  listen to multiple container is not possible.**